# How to send none input element from html to python

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

A part of my script, I have html JavaScript code like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Save").click(function(){
var FormDesc = ['Account','Account Report','Account Drawdown'];
            $.ajax({
                url:'/url/updateMenu',
                type:'GET',
                data:{FormDesc:FormDesc}
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log('data return');
               console.log(data);
            })
});
})
```

In my `view.py`, I try to retrieve an variable `FormDesc` for further processing, my script like this.

```
from flask                      import request, url_for, render_template,flash,redirect,session, flash
from ..                         import app, db
from jinja2                     import Template

@app.route("/url/updateMenu", methods=['GET','POST'])
# @checkLogOutSession
# @checkLogOutTime
def getMenuToUpdate():

    getDesc      = request.args.get('FormDesc') if 'FormDesc' in request.args else 'Not received get Form Desc'

    print "===================="
    print "Form Description is ", getDesc
    print "===================="
```

However, I could not retrieve an variable `FromDesc`. From console, it show result like this:

```
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 332-799-490
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
====================
Form Description is 1  Not received get Form Desc
====================
====================
====================
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2017 20:52:21] "GET /url/MenuBuilder HTTP/1.1" 200 -
====================
Form POST Description is 1  Not received get Form Desc
====================
====================
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2017 20:52:25] "GET /url/updateMenu?FormDesc%5B%5D=Account&FormDesc%5B%5D=Account+Report&FormDesc%5B%5D=Account+Drawdown
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

How can I get an array of `FormDesc` sent from html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use json.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Save").click(function(){
var FormDesc = ['Account','Account Report','Account Drawdown'];
            $.ajax({
                url:'/url/updateMenu',
                type:'GET',
                data:JSON.stringify({'FormDesc':FormDesc}),
                contentType : "application/json",
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log('data return');
               console.log(data);
            })
});
})
```

And change your view.py file to

```
@app.route("/url/updateMenu", methods=['GET','POST'])
# @checkLogOutSession
# @checkLogOutTime
def getMenuToUpdate():
    getDesc = request.json['FormDesc']
    print "===================="
    print "Form Description is ", getDesc
    print "===================="
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I will test it and will let you know result, thanks!

Comment: I tried following your answer, however, it still does not work. from console i got `127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2017 19:46:28] "GET /url/updateMenu?{%22FormDesc%22:[%22Account%22,%22Account%20Report%22,%22Account%20Drawdown%22]} HTTP/1.1
" 400 -`. I thought it already parsed array to JSON format, but it could not be retrieved inside a `view.py`.  Thanks

Comment: I finally solved the program. From your answer I tried changing `$.ajax` method type to `POST` and get the print the sent variable from html if the method is `POST` like: `if request.method == 'POST': getDesc = request.json['FormDesc'] print "Form Description is 1 ", getDesc`. Then in the console, I got the result as a list like this: `Form Description is 1  [u'Account', u'Account Report', u'Account Drawdown']`.  Anyway, could you slightly update your answer accordingly to be fit? I will accept it as the only Answer. Thanks once again, for solution to me it's really help :)